# add additional middleware to specific route in a route group Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
 Route::group([
    'middleware' =>['JwtMiddleware', 'auth:api'],
    'prefix' => 'courses'
], function () {
    Route::get('/', [CourseController::class, 'index']);
    Route::post('/', [CourseController::class, 'create']);
    Route::get('/{course}', [CourseController::class, 'show']);
    Route::put('/{course}', [CourseController::class, 'update']);
    Route::delete('/{course}', [CourseController::class, 'delete']);
});
```

This is my route Group How Can I add another `'can:isSuperAdmin'` middleware to only `POST`,`PUT`and `Delete` Methods without writing it outside(without repeating the route) In laravel

Answer (score 1):

```
 Route::group([
    'middleware' =>['JwtMiddleware', 'auth:api'],
    'prefix' => 'courses'
], function () {
    Route::get('/', [CourseController::class, 'index']);
    Route::post('/', [CourseController::class, 'create'])->middleware('can:isSuperAdmin');
    Route::get('/{course}', [CourseController::class, 'show']);
    Route::put('/{course}', [CourseController::class, 'update'])->middleware('can:isSuperAdmin');;
    Route::delete('/{course}', [CourseController::class, 'delete'])->middleware('can:isSuperAdmin');;
});
```

OR

```
 Route::group([
    'middleware' =>['JwtMiddleware', 'auth:api'],
    'prefix' => 'courses'
], function () {
    Route::get('/', [CourseController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/{course}', [CourseController::class, 'show']);

    Route::group([
        'middleware' =>['can:isSuperAdmin'],
        ], function () {
            Route::post('/', [CourseController::class, 'create']);
            Route::put('/{course}', [CourseController::class, 'update']);
            Route::delete('/{course}', [CourseController::class, 'delete']);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     Route::group([
    'middleware' =>['JwtMiddleware', 'auth:api'],
    'prefix' => 'courses'
], function () {
    Route::get('/', [CourseController::class, 'index']);
    Route::post('/', [CourseController::class, 'create'])->middleware([
        'can:isSuperAdmin'
    ]);
    Route::get('/{course}', [CourseController::class, 'show']);
    Route::put('/{course}', [CourseController::class, 'update'])->middleware([
        'can:isSuperAdmin'
    ]);
    Route::delete('/{course}', [CourseController::class, 'delete']);
});
```